# To prove $abc\leq\frac 18$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive real numbers such that 
>   $$\frac a{1 + b} + \frac b{1 + c} + \frac c{1 + a} = 1.$$ 
>   Prove that $$abc \leq \frac 18.$$

I have tried to simply and get answer of this inequalities

Please help me to solve this question.

Comment: I have tried  to simply and get answer of this inequalities

Comment: @DwipDalal You should always mention what you've tried, no matter how trivial, in the question, so that we can help you better. Also, people will be more willing to help if you show that you have put effort into it. As a personal comment, saying that "I've tried to get the answer" doesn't seem very specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

expanding the condition we get
$$a^2c+ab^2+bc^2+a^2+b^2+c^2=abc+1$$
and then we have
$$1+abc\geq 3\sqrt[3]{(abc)^3}+3\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}$$ this is equivalent to
$$1-2abc\geq 3\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}$$
expanding we get
$$-8(abc)^3-15(abc)^2-6abc+1\geq 0$$ this equivalent to
$$(1-8abc)(abc+1)^2\geq 0$$ therefore $$abc\le \frac{1}{8}$$

Comment: Sonnhard I think it's exactly my solution. I think it's not fair, which you did.

Comment: sorry Michael, i have not copied your solution, why do you think so about me?

Comment: it is not so rairly that two Solutions in mathematics are similiar

Comment: You posted this solution later. If you see that someone posted the same solution you need to delete your. Otherwise it's not fair. Our posts are not similar. They are the same.

Comment: ok if you think so about me, i will delete my solution.

Comment: they say to me that i can not delete this post

Comment: Sonnhard Say to Dwip Dalal that he'll remove the accept and after this delete please your post.

Answer (score 1):

Let $abc=w^3$.

Thus, since the expanding gives
$$1+abc=\sum_{cyc}(a^2+a^2c),$$
by AM-GM we obtain:
$$1+w^3\geq3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}+3abc=3w^2+3w^3$$ or
$$2w^3+3w^2-1\leq0$$ or
$$2w^3-w^2+4w^2-2w+2w-1\leq0$$ or
$$(2w-1)(w+1)^2\leq0$$ or
$$w\leq\frac{1}{2}$$ or
$$abc\leq\frac{1}{8}.$$
Done!

Comment: You have a $+4a^2$ there when you mean $+4w^2$.

Comment: It was typo. Thank you  Thomas!

Comment: Can you please explain me how did you shift from 1st step to 2nd step that is from 1+abc=∑cyc(a2+a2c) to  1+w^3>3a2b2c2√3+3abc

Comment: @Dwip Dalal Yes, of course! $\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2=a^2+b^2+c^2\geq3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}=3\sqrt[3]{w^6}=3w^2$ and $\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2c=a^2c+b^2a+c^2b\geq3\sqrt[3]{a^3b^3c^3}=3\sqrt[3]{w^9}=3w^3$. Because $abc=w^3$.