# Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers such that $\frac{a}{1+a}+\frac{b}{1+b}+\frac{c}{1+c}=1.$ Prove that $abc \le \frac{1}{8}$.

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers such that $$\frac{a}{1+a}+\frac{b}{1+b}+\frac{c}{1+c}=1.$$ Prove that $abc \le \frac{1}{8}$.

---

So I tried this problem and came up with a solution, but I'm afraid it might have logical fallacies as I'm not too good playing with inequalities.$$\frac{a}{1+a}+\frac{b}{1+b}+\frac{c}{1+c}=1.$$ $\Rightarrow \frac{a}{1+a}-1+\frac{b}{1+b}-1+\frac{c}{1+c}-1=-2$
$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{1}{1+b}+\frac{1}{1+c}=2$. Now by AM GM inequality, $\begin{aligned} & \frac{\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{1}{1+b}+\frac{1}{1+c}}{3} \geqslant \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)}} \\ \Rightarrow \quad &\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3 \geqslant \frac{1}{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)} \\ \Rightarrow \quad &(1+a)(1+b)(1+c) \geqslant \frac{27}{8} \end{aligned}$. So the minimum value of the expression $(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)$ is $27/8$. From the original equation, applying am gm inequality, we get,$\frac{\frac{a}{1+a}+\frac{b}{1+b}+\frac{c}{1+c}}{3} \geqslant \sqrt[3]{\frac{a b c}{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)}}$
$\Rightarrow \quad \frac{1}{27} \geqslant \frac{a b c}{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)}$
$\Rightarrow \frac{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)}{27} \geqslant a b c$. The minimum value of $\frac{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)}{27}$ is attained when $(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)$ is minimum, which is $\frac {27}{8}$. So $min(\frac{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)}{27})= \frac {1}{8}$. Hence, $\frac {1}{8} \geq abc$. Is this correct? **I want to clarify I'm not looking for any solution but rather a clarification on my solution**. Thank you.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3314258/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2294748/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2460344/42969

Comment: @MartinR yes there are solutions available. But I wanted to check if my solution is correct or not, as I stated at the end of my post .

Comment: There's a particular tag you should include when that is what you are looking for; it has been added now.

Answer (score 1):

The key step in your proof is the following:
$$f(a,b,c)\geq M \text{ and } f(a,b,c)\geq g(a,b,c)\implies g(a,b,c)\leq M.$$

This is a flawed reasoning - for example take $f = 2+a^2, g = 1+a^2$ and $M = 1.$ If you are wondering your line of reasoning can be salvaged, then unfortunately no because for $a = b = 1, c = \dfrac{4}{23}$ satisfies:
$$(1+a)(1+b)(1+c) = 27abc$$ but $abc = \dfrac{4}{23} > \dfrac{1}{8}.$

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is wrong because the last reasoning is wrong:

From $$\frac{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)}{27}\geq abc$$ not follows that $abc\leq\frac{1}{8}.$

The right solution:   by AM-GM $$\prod_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+1}=\prod_{cyc}\left(\frac{b}{b+1}+\frac{c}{c+1}\right)\geq8\prod_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{bc}{(b+1)(c+1)}}=\frac{8abc}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+1)}.$$

Comment: You have answered the same question (at least) three times already: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2460355/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2294791/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3314278/42969.

Comment: I appreciate your solution. But as I mentioned at the end of my post, i am not looking for new solution but rather a clarification of my own solution. Thank you.

Comment: @轻型八神 I think, your solution is wrong. I added something. See now.